# Chrome -webkit-animation-play-state flicker

Tags: css

I'm rotating a circle with CSS3 and pause / run the animation with **-webkit-animation-play-state** on hovering the div. As soon as it starts to run again the animation seems to jump back to the start just for a split second in Chrome. In Safari everything starts and stops smooth.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5AZy/

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if in Safari it works okay, it means the mistake is not in your code. The only thing could be to wait for a future version of Chrome that corrects this feature.

Comment: Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Just came over this issue myself. chrome 30.0.1599.101 on osx. It works on safari.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, animation and hover are two heavy operations. Right now, animation is still new and not very stable. Therefore, if you want to remove the flickering, remove the hover.
You can try to apply the hover on another div, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can help, give me feedback later

[Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)

Try to

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

*Good Lucky*