# css3 animation artifacts

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have some weird issues with **css3 animation**.

I have block elements with `css3 transformation` applied.
When transformation applied with **-webkit-transform matrix** — elements look very smooth.
But when i try to apply animation with **-webkit-keyframes** , fonts and some other div's look awful during animation.

Sample can be found here: http://shuma.ru/animation.html

Issues can be seen in 'webkit browsers Safari / Chrome' etc.

Comment: This problem also actual for Firefox

Answer (score 9):

For this problem you can write this on you css.

```
body{
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

& for safari define this :

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

in the animated element CSS Check this for more

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Unfortunately, this solution didn't work for my case...

Comment: Check this link for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform