# CSS transition width on Chrome ghosting

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

This css changing width from 80px to 120px on hover:

```
-webkit-transition: width .5s ease, color .5s ease, background .5s ease;
-moz-transition: width .5s ease, color .5s ease, background .5s ease;
-o-transition: width .5s ease, color .5s ease, background .5s ease;
transition: width .5s ease, color .5s ease, background .5s ease;
```

Is resulting in this problem:

[image]

On Chrome (24.0.1312.57 on Mac) when the width returns back to 80px.

The problem is not present on Safari.

Is this a known issue, or is there a way to fix this?

mjohnst.com is the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't test it, I assume that the problem is that background image under the *about* element.

Try removing the background image and test if that gives you a problem. And then you'll be closer to solution.

I put an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/69LQj/). Markup looks like this:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="trans">
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

#### Update #1

Sorry, but I cannot test it on Mac OS, and to not shoot in the dark see similar question and try all possible methods from there [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform).

Comment: I think you're right, the example you put up works fine.  How should I fix the issue with the background image? mjohnst.com if you want to see

Comment: I've tried with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` on animated element and I think the flicker (I have it too on chrome but it's hardly noticable) goes away ...

Comment: The link you provided in the update gave me the answer.  I had to add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to my `body {background-image:url(...);}` CSS