# Slideshow Causes Weird Graphical Glitch

Tags: css, google-chrome

Unfortunately I can't reproduce this in a JSFiddle or otherwise, when I do it simply works properly.  From there I still was not able to narrow it down to figure out what is causing it.  Here is the link to the development site:

http://dev.fusion-inc.net

This bug is only visible in Chrome, I am using the latest version, and the problem still appeared on the previous version (I just updated this morning).

Watch the links in the content of the home page carefully, when the image slider transitions, you will see a change in the text of the links.  It's almost as if the anti-aliasing changes somehow and causes the text to become just a smidge thinner.  You may need to zoom in to see it well.

Any idea what's causing this?  I'm completely stumped, the only thing I can figure is something in the rendering of the animation of the slider is tweaking some anti-aliasing or something causing the fonts to move a bit.  Even the youtube and linked in images in the footer have the same problem.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Diodeus I am well aware of the rules, this is a particularly unique situation that requires debugging in a live state.  Pray tell Diodeus how am I to avoid that?

Comment: You don't. StackOverflow's purpose is to build up a knowledge base, not to fix narrowly-focused individual problems. They aren't my rules.

Comment: Hardly narrowly focused seeing as how a more experienced individual in chat was able to provide me with a topic that solved my problem that apparently is a fairly broad issue.  Easily salvageable through a well written answer by someone who is not terminally lazy, something I and many others strive to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#content * {-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

The above fixed it thanks to someone in Chat.

Similar problems should reference this link: [Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)