# 1px (or less? subpixel?) border on inline SVG in FF25 and IE10, not Chrome

Tags: css, svg

I am running into a weird issue when using an inline SVG. I am creating a path in an `<svg>` element and using `top` or `bottom` CSS attributes with `relative` positioning to superimpose this SVG over a previous element to get a cool "cutout" effect on the section.

This totally works in Chrome, but in **IE10** and **FF25**, I get this 'transparent' border to the right and top of the SVG. I put 'transparent' in quotes because as far as I know it is transparent since it is showing the bright green background that is underneath it. Here's a screenshot pointing to exactly where I'm seeing this (screenshot is from FF25):

[image: SVG Border Issue in Firefox 25]

I had originally gotten the separator suggestion from [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/03/a-collection-of-separator-styles/).

### [Test Page](http://ignitepixels.com/sandbox/svg/)

In this test page, the section with a header of "**SVG Trouble Section**" is the section with the issue.

Is there anyway to aleviate this issue so my technique works fine cross-browser? Or is there a better way to achieve the effect I am going for? Thanks!

---

**Update 1:**
Through a little more testing, I have found that sometimes while scrolling in Firefox, the top phantom 'border' disappears and doesn't return. Even after reloading the page. I'm not sure what is causing this to disappear and it isn't part of the problem, just an anomaly.

**Update 2:**
I've done some additional testing by removing elements to see what may be triggering this and after removing comments, a few sections above the "SVG Trouble Section", and the footer, the border has now moved to the bottom separator. Here's the page without the footer: http://ignitepixels.com/sandbox/svg/sample.html

**Update 3:**
I've created a fiddle in which I replicated the issue. This should make for easier troubleshooting: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/NuneR/

Since you can't save specific panel sizes in jsfiddle, I've attached a screenshot of the approximate size I was able to reproduce this issue with Firefox 25:
[image: Fiddle in Firefox 25]
Possibly related to Update 1, the issue shows/disappears based on the window width as well.

Comment: 1+ Tested in FF.. So many cross browser inconsistencies. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thank you for testing! I'm glad its happening on other users' browsers and not just mine.

Comment: The with of the "border" changes when I zoom (ctrl + scroll) so I guess this is a pixel rounding error.
A workaround that seems to work is to set stroke-width to 5 and stroke to white

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a rounding error or an `svg` anti-aliasing painting issue, but I have only found the following to work consistently on both Firefox and IE10 in my testing ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/NuneR/7/embedded/result/)):

**Change both SVG paths to this**

Note the extra `.1` added at two places

```
<path class="white" d="M0 100 L50 0 L100.1 100 L100.1 0 L0 0 L0 100 Z"></path>
```

**Change the `top`/`bottom` offsets of those elements**

Change the offsets from `-20px` to `-19.5px`

**Add this to `.separator`**

```
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

What I don't know for sure is just how fragile this solution may be.

Comment: Definitely looks promising. I tested your fiddle in FF25 and IE10 and the issue seems resolved. I will try the solution in my project and get back to you.

Comment: I applied this technique to my project and it seems to indeed work and solve my issue. This is likely the answer that will gain the bounty, but I wanted to leave it open in case there is an answer can explain exactly why FF25/IE10 are behaving this way, and a proper, clean, 'non-hacky' way of solving this.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and reward this bounty to @ScottS, since it will be rewarded to him anyway. I would love if anyone found the exact reason why this isn't behaving properly or a non-hacky way of solving this. Thanks again @ScottS!

Answer (score 2):

Another work-around is to add the following rules to section.green.

```
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

Comment: A good work-around, but only if my background image is indeed white. While this is the case in this scenario, I am looking for a solution that would allow for complex backgrounds (images, gradients, etc.)

Comment: @FillipPeyton: Your svg on the green section is filling with a solid color of white, so it would not work against complex backgrounds anyway. Also, it would be nice for you to reproduce this in a fiddle or some form that we could easily manipulate for testing.

Comment: That is true. Not sure why that didn't come to mind. Might've been thinking of another section of the page. I'll try reproducing in a fiddle.

Comment: @ScottS, I have reproduced the issue in a fiddle. Please see **Update 3** in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an svg graphic where i used tween-maxjs on it. Only in chrome I got a flickering border. I tried the recommended solutions from above but it didnt change anything.

So i found this article: [Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)

and the key was:
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

I hope that will help someone struggling with the same problem.
Cheers :)