# img flickering on css picture wall

Tags: php, html, css

im doing this project for university. i'm currently facing a minor problem but yet disturbing.

link to site: http://haw.finekost.com/ws2013/PP_HATE_SITE/

CSS:

```
.box {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    o-filter: grayscale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    position: relative;
    webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    width: 20%;
}

.box:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    moz-filter: all .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the boxes are generated via php.
the image boxes change in size (just 1px) when i hover them. i really dont know why they do it. Hopefully someone can help me

Comment: In Firefox on OSX they don't actually, in Chrome they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to be related to the webkit transition filter in your .box:hover

Maybe this will help?
[Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)

actually if you add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to the box:hover css it appears this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to your webkit-transition style rule setup on your box:hover selector.

If you take it out, then there is no 'flicker'. THe reason it does not happen in Firefox is because you do not have a firefox vendor property set there such as -moz-transition.

Why do you need a transition in this case ?

Comment: oh and if you do need the webkit transition to gracefully transition into the hovered over picture. The remove 'all', it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your website you use for `.box` a width of `20%`. It looks like this causes somehow a 1px gap. However this could be solved by using `width: 20vw` for `.box`. 
`vw` is viewport width in % this removed the 1px border.

So use:

```
.box {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    ms-filter: grayscale(1);
    o-filter: grayscale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    padding-bottom: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
}
```