# jQuery slideToggle causing background blink

Tags: jquery

Weird behaviour going on with my dropdown menu. (Click the menu button in the left next to the name.)

http://zeltser.waterstreetgm.org

Resize your browser to be mobile-sized. When you hit the menu button, the background "blinks" before the menu comes down. Blinks even worse when it toggles back up.

Thanks for any ideas for making this not be so terrible.

Comment: Looks fine in chrome 36.0.1985.125 m. and Firefox 30.0
What reselution is your 'mobile' size?

Comment: The smallest chrome gives me on desktop — so, 400px I think?  But it looks jaggy on my iPhone (Chrome) as well.

Comment: It's especially pronounced on a content page: http://zeltser.waterstreetgm.org/remnux-v5-release-for-malware-analysts/#

Comment: Try redesigning the whole page... joking. How about Safari, thats native to iPhone, surely it should perform the best on iOS.

Comment: I've had these issues before, have you tried setting `webkit-backface-visibility` CSS property? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform

Comment: Does the blink thing in Safari too.  There's something I'm not doing right, for sure.

Comment: I think the whole thing is flawed. I'm loading several dropdowns in that one div and I think it needs to load them all everytime a button is pressed. I think I need to do something like here on the Starbucks site:  http://www.starbucks.com/menu