# white screen always show before transition while using JQuery mobile changePage

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am making single page app with Backbone, JQuery mobile, when I use JQuery changePage to switch views(pages), white screen always showes before transition(testing on Android), have tried out solutions found on StackOverflow, but still problem existing. So is there better solution to solve it?

Comment: Try the -webkit-backface-visibility fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform

Comment: have tried this: .ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}, dose not make difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Solution:

```
Change:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

To:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Then white screen disappear.