# Chrome + Safari opacity transition bug creates st

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have a bug on a opacity transition in both Chrome and Safari. When I hover over a parent div that triggers a opacity transition from 0 to 1 on a child div, content beneath the child div jitters for a split moment.

I've tried using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` on the `body`, but the effect still occurs. Any ideas why? You can see the issue [here](https://www.dcturano.com/faq/) (using either Chrome or Safari, hover over the 'Account' link in the top menu and you'll see the flicker).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element, or to all elements with `*` if you feel like setting a blanket statement.

A few links describing the issue in greater detail:

[Prevent flicker on webkit-transition of webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461441/prevent-flicker-on-webkit-transition-of-webkit-transform)

[How to fix flicker when using Webkit transforms & transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975217/how-to-fix-flicker-when-using-webkit-transforms-transitions?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer John. Would it be fine to apply `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the body selector?

Comment: As long as it fixes the flicker and doesn't cause any other issues, then it should be ok. As with anything, it has the potential to create problems of its own, so it might be best to only target the specific elements that are causing problems.